# An integral involving a dirac

Tags: dynamical-systems, dirac-delta

Let $x(t)$ a process with a differentiable trajectory. How do you understand $\int_0^t |\dot{x}(s)| \delta_{x(s) = 0} d s$?

Comment: Dirac "functions" (which are not functions) are **defined** by the fact that $\int_I f(t)\, \delta_{t_0}(t)\,dt = f(t_0)$. In your case, the notation is a bit peculiar, because the condition $x(s)=0$ does not define a single point (unless you've hidden some hypotheses). Is there at least a reason for this equation $x(s)=0$ to have a finite number of solutions? or a discrete set of solutions?

Comment: According to **André Preumont in Random Vibrations and Spectral Analysis, page 190, formula 10.3.** Such a formula gives the average number of crossing of $0$ by $x(t)$. I think the book's explanation is a bit handwavy. I am trying to understand that from a rigorous viewpoint.

Comment: Try using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087041/how-to-prove-this-dirac-delta-identity-involving-int-infty-infty-deltaf?rq=1). The answer there also mentions a number of scenarios that you may want to check.

Comment: $$\int y(s) \delta_{x(s) = 0} d s=\sum_{s:x(s)=0}\frac{y(s)}{|x'(s)|}$$